# Htop load average 30

Tags: linux, htop, load-average

I'm running an application which, for now, uses the bakery algorithm for syncronizing `n` processes, but with this method I do a lot of busy waiting on my CPU, in fact as you can see from the title, I have a load avg of `20`, `30`, `10`, etc.. depending on how many processes I decide to fork.

Is it dangerous for my PC to have such a load? Could I damage the computer by running this app for 1 minute straight?

EDIT: I have 4 cores.

Comment: The load average is the average number of processes running/waiting for CPU time in a given time period.  It has no direct relationship to how much work those processes are doing (they could all be idle, or they could all be using 100% of all 4 cores whenever they get scheduled to run), and therefore no relationship to how much heat their workload is generating.  CPUs can be damaged by excess heat (i.e. heat beyond what its heatsink and cooler fan or whatever can get rid of), not just by running lots of processes.

Comment: if your system can't run all cores at 100% sustained for a long period of time (i.e. "indefinitely"), then you need to improve the cooling system.  e.g. bigger, better heatsink and fan, or a liquid cooling rig.

Comment: Yes these processes use the CPU at 100%, thanks

Answer (score 1):

@cas 's response is what i needed:

The load average is the average number of processes running/waiting for CPU time in a given time period. It has no direct relationship to how much work those processes are doing (they could all be idle, or they could all be using 100% of all 4 cores whenever they get scheduled to run), and therefore no relationship to how much heat their workload is generating. CPUs can be damaged by excess heat (i.e. heat beyond what its heatsink and cooler fan or whatever can get rid of), not just by running lots of processes. – cas 11 hours ago

if your system can't run all cores at 100% sustained for a long period of time (i.e. "indefinitely"), then you need to improve the cooling system. e.g. bigger, better heatsink and fan, or a liquid cooling rig